# Does "the cornet of horse" mean a knight/rider?

Tags: literary-english

The original sentence:

> The first that stood up, to open the ball, were a cornet of horse, and that sweetest of olive-beauties, the soft and amorous Louisa.

http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Fanny_Hill:_Memoirs_of_a_Woman_of_Pleasure/Letter_the_Second/Part_7

Comment: This definition of [cornet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cornet) carries your answer (expand to meaning 8).

Comment: Have you searched the phrase in a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matt hasn't expanded his comment into an answer, I will.  In [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cornet), sense 8 of *cornet* is

> (formerly) the officer who carried the colors in a troop of cavalry: the cornet of horse.

Thus,  “the soft and amorous Louisa” (a woman) and a [cavalry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cavalry#Noun) officer (a man) were the first couple of the ball.  As Felix Goldberg commented,  “cornet here is meant as a subaltern rank”;  [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornet_%28military_rank%29) says:

> The subaltern rank of Cornet was the equivalent of the contemporary infantry rank of ensign, today’s Second lieutenant in each [service]. The cornet carried the troop standard, known as a “cornet”.

A related meaning of  “cornet of horse” is given in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cornet#Noun):

> (obsolete) A troop of cavalry; so called from its being accompanied by a cornet player. [eg] A body of five cornets of horse (Clarendon)

In the latter example, sense 3 of *[horse](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/horse#Noun)* applies:

> (military, sometimes uncountable) Cavalry soldiers (sometimes capitalized when referring to an official category).  [eg] We should place two units of horse and one of foot on this side of the field.

Comment: To be even more precise, I think cornet here is meant as a subaltern rank: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornet_%28military_rank%29

Comment: It's not strictly obsolete; the Blues and Royals (an armoured unit, who fought in the Falklands and Iraq) still use the term *cornet* where other regiments use *lieutenant*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blues_and_Royals.  Other ex-cavalry units have the same tradition, but the Guards are likely to maintain it longest.

Comment: Obviously, Matt has only commented and not posted an answer because the Q is GR.

Comment: Wiktionary is wrong. The cavalry usage refers to 'cornet' meaning the troop standard, not a musical instrument.